# Overriding import method of a Moose class

Tags: perl, moose

I have two Perl classes.  Let's call one `Client`, the other `Server`.  `Server` is a well defined Moose class.  `Client` is not a Moose class, and is just a very thin facade to connect to a `Server` object over a network.

Furthermore, `Client` is internal to our project and shouldn't be used by anyone else.  Now at our company, other developers cannot always be trusted.  To help notify them that they're doing something wrong, our `Client` class has a custom import statement:

```
package Client;

sub import {
    my ($self, $promise) = @_;
    die "this is not a public API"
        unless $promise eq "Only CertainTeam should be using this API";
}

sub do_something { ... }
```

So in order for someone to use `Client`, they would have to type:

```
use Client q{Only CertainTeam should be using this API};
```

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but it has worked nicely in deterring other teams from using `Client`.  I'd now like to make `Client` a Moose class.  However, perl is pretty unhappy when I add `use Moose;`, as I am now overriding Moose's import.  I get the following error:

```
Prototype mismatch: sub Client::with: none vs (&;$) at Client.pm line 14
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I can persist the import behavior of `Client` while making it a Moose class?

Comment: Anyone could bypass this with a simple `use Client ()`. Are you sure this isn't solvable by just installing `Client` in a different location (somewhere those pesky other developers don't have access)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message has nothing to do with your `import` method. You are not overriding an `import` method that Moose has installed into your class, because Moose doesn't install any such method into your class.

It is because Moose exports a function called `with`, but your package already contains a function called `with`. At a guess, you're using the venerable [Error.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/Error) for exception handling; that exports a function called `with`. This is a [known incompatibility](https://metacpan.org/pod/Error#COMPATIBILITY).

My suggestions:

- Error.pm is no longer recommended by its maintainers. For try/catch, switch to [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try%3a%3aTiny).
- The Error::Simple base class for exceptions is part of the same distribution as Error.pm. Consider switching to [Throwable::Error](https://metacpan.org/pod/Throwable%3a%3aError).
- This `import` method seems like a pretty weird attempt at security. How about renaming the `Client` class something like `CertainTeam::Internal::Client`? While this wouldn't stop other people using it, anybody who litters their code with references to what is clearly another team's internal client is inviting trouble. The only guarantee they get is that if their code breaks, they can keep both halves.

Comment: Sure enough, buried in nested dependencies, something is using Error.pm.  Thanks for the suggestions, but at least #1 & #2 are out of my control in this instance.  I'll attempt to convince the powers that be of #3 because it really *is* a bizarre way to try & restrict access and only causes headaches.

Comment: Well, it's perfectly allowable to import two `with` functions from different places. The last one you import "wins". You'll get this annoying warning message, but you can do a `no warnings qw(redefine prototype)` to disable that.